# Spiting data from a text file into different .txt files java file handling

Tags: java, split, io, bufferedreader

I have a specific text file, containing data(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). I am required to divide the contents of text file in group of 3 txt files using file handling. Each txt file  must contain 3 entries, any help would be appreciated, THANKS!

Comment: Show us what you have tried thus far? What seems to be the error within your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to simply open the specific input file using FileInputStream
and the three output files using FileOutputStream.

Then simply read 3 chars at a time from the input file and write to the output files using the .read() and .write() functions respectively..

You can look up how to use these functions here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm